# The antonyms of infinity

Tags: antonyms

I often see words like: **nonfinity**, and **nofinity**.

Mostly on T-shirts or on signs.

Are all these words antonyms of the word **infinity**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One *actual* antonym of "infinity" is "finity" - although I've never actually *seen* "finity" used anywhere. "Boundedness" and "finiteness" are more typical antonyms that I've seen - although perhaps mathematicians would use "finity".

"Nonfinity" and "nofinity" are slang - I haven't seen them before. I would actually interpret them as *synonyms* of "infinity", though that may be incorrect.

Here's why: the prefix "in" means "no" or "not" - something that is "indivisible" cannot be divided. So the "in" in "infinity" is *negating* "finity". In "nonfinity" and "nofinity", the "non" and "no" prefixes are *also* negating "finity".

So that's why I would assume that "nonfinity" and "nofinity" are synonyms of "infinity". But again, that may not be accurate; one of the downsides of coining a new word is that its meaning may be non-obvious. ;)

Comment: Clearly, the antonym of _infinity_ should be _outfinity_.

Comment: But if infinity means no finity then does finity really mean the opposite of infinity?

Comment: _infinity_ does not mean "no finity"; _infinite_ means "not finite", and _infinity_ is derived as a noun form of _infinite_.